# Android 2.0 and OpenGL ES 2.0 support

Tags: android, opengl-es

can I assume that, if a phone runs Android 2.0, it also supports OpenGL ES 2.0 and thus the graphic hardware has full support for programmable shaders?

IOW, does Android 2.0 as a platform mandate OpenGL ES 2.0 support? Or is it optional?

Comment: try glGetString(GL_VERSION) and glGetString(GL_VENDOR) for more info at runtime http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GlGetString

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7-62tRHLcHk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't mandate it.  Its also ONLY available via the NDK.

Comment: so I could find Android 2.2 phones with OpenGL ES 1.1?